# Rx.js, ofObjectChanges, and Object.observe

Tags: javascript, rxjs

This may be too speculative a question for StackOverflow, but still.

Among all the goodness that `Rx.js`’s Observables are capable of, is observing changes of object properties through the `ofObjectChanges` method. Since the `ofObjectChanges` method is [implemented](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/ofobjectchanges.md) using `Object.observe`, and since `Object.observe` is on its way out and won't make it into JavaScript spec, is it a good idea to watch for object property changes using Rx.js's `ofObjectChanges`? Are there any better ways of observing object’s properties?